# How to open a pull request on github for an improvement in a bitbucket fork?

Tags: github, bitbucket, pull-request, github-cli

I cloned a github repository into our Bitbucket account. Similar to https://gist.github.com/sangeeths/9467061.

I fixed a bug in my repository located in bitbucket. I'd like to open a pull request on the original github repository that fixes the bug.

If my fork were located on github, I would simply follow [these instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork), but since my fork is on bitbucket, I don't know where to start.

How can I open a pull request from my bitbucket repo to the original github repo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- clone the original GitHub repository to a different folder
- add your local BitBucket repo as a remote
- fetch your fix branch (make sure you fix is done in its own branch, not `master`)
- create a PR using the [cli/cli](https://github.com/cli/cli) GitHub command line interface gh pr create

That is:

```
git clone https://github.com/original/repo
cd repo
git remote add bb ../yourLocalBitbucket/repo
git fetch bb
git checkout bb/fix
gh pr create
```

The [gh pr create](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) command will do the work for you:

> When the current branch isn’t fully pushed to a git remote, a prompt will ask where to push the branch and offer an option to fork the base repository.

Comment: It'd be cool if `gh` can support all `git` commands so I don't have to alternate between `git` and `gh`. But I guess it can be solved by using alias.

Comment: @NearHuscarl True. I suspect it is because `gh` is really oriented to GitHub, while `git` remains... well, for Git.